# 'Access is denied' while trying to generate executable using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
python = 3.8.0

pyinstaller=5.2

commands
   pyinstaller --onefile Main.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 188, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\com\git\testme.spec", line 24, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 524, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 692, in assemble
    self.manifest.update_resources(build_name, [1])
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 904, in update_resources
    UpdateManifestResourcesFromXML(dstpath, self.toprettyxml().encode("UTF-8"), names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 992, in UpdateManifestResourcesFromXML
    winresource.UpdateResources(dstpath, xmlstr, RT_MANIFEST, names or [name], languages or [0, "*"])
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 189, in UpdateResources
    win32api.EndUpdateResource(hdst, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 228, in EndUpdateResource
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Testuser\Documents\installed\Python\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (5, 'EndUpdateResource', 'Access is denied')
```

Comment: Your program might not have permission to install - have you made sure you don't have any anti-ransomware software that is preventing your program from running (it might send a notification)

Comment: This can happen in a debugging situation if you are still running the last version of the executable.

Comment: Look [this link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6917) and also [this link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6062)

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge you are right its because of McAFee anti-virus.